# OS.rename creates a file but doesn't rename the existing file?

Tags: python

I tried to rename my existing file, "test.py" to "test1.py".
It just creates a new file called "test1.py" instead of renaming "test.py" to "test1.py".

My code is below.

```
import os
os.rename("test.py", "test1.py")
```

Comment: this code runs perfectly, please make sure that **test.py** is in the same directory

Comment: Can't reproduce. Ran three scenarios: 1. No `test.py` file exists - error raised ; 2. exists - changed to `test1.py` ; 3. From within a `test.py` file - it was changed to `test1.py`

Comment: The code should run perfectly. Can you make sure that test.py is not recreated somehow?

Comment: I guess that he tries to rename a file that he is currently running.

Comment: You're probably looking in the wrong directory...